# Not able to send API requests from eclipse/Intellij

Tags: java, eclipse, api, proxy

Im trying to send a get request to an api using eclipse or intellij as part of a test using java/junit and the rest assured frame work.

Each request fails, with the following message

Mar 13, 2018 1:29:56 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to {s}->http://swapi.co:443: Connection reset

By the way, im attempting this on my work machine/network which uses a proxy

I am able to send the same request manually using postman and this works fine so I dont think there is a problem at the server end.

Does anyone know if there are some settings that i need to change in my ide in order to get this working correctly?

for reference this is the code im trying to run:

```
@Test

public void canGetLuke(){
    given().relaxedHTTPSValidation().
    when().get("http://swapi.co/api/people/1/?format=json").
            then().
            assertThat().
            body("name",
                    equalTo("Luke Skywalker"));

    }
```

in addition, these are the network connection settigns in eclipse
[image]

Comment: Try connecting using HTTPS

Comment: I forgot to mention that both HTTP and HTTPS do not work, resulting in the same message detailed in my original post

Comment: The IDE settings for its network usage do not affect your application.

Answer (score 0):

Under `Run configurations` or `Debug configurations`, in the `Arguments` tab, you can add the proxy settings that the VM will use. Try setting the following params with your proxy host and port:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost="your.proxy.com"

-Dhttp.proxyPort="8080"
```

Comment: Hi Unfortunately this did not work. The solution i found was to add my proxy settings, either in a given statement or in and @Before method

Answer (score 0):

I ended up one of the doing one the following:

Add proxy to a method:

```
@Test

public void canGetLuke(){
given().proxy("my.proxy.com", 8080).
when().get("https://swapi.co/api/people/1/?format=json").
        then().
        assertThat().
        body("name",
                equalTo("Luke Skywalker"));

}
```

or use the proxy settings in an @Before method like so:

```
@Before
        public void setProxy() {

    proxy("my.proxy.com", 8080);

}
```

Both of the above approaches worked for me
Also had to send the request as https

Answer (score 0):

To extend @JPinzon01's answer, you may need to set HTTP and HTTPS settings

HTTP

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost="your.proxy.com"
-Dhttp.proxyPort="8080"
```

HTTPS

```
-Dhttps.proxyHost="your.proxy.com"
-Dhttps.proxyPort="8080"
```